# Is ePub3 backward compatible?

Tags: epub, publishing

I am planning to publish a book and I am wondering whether to distribute it as ePub3 or ePub4. My concern being that older eBook readers may still be out there and I do not wish to exclude them. I would prefer ePub3 if the older readers are able to read it.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean: are you asking if older readers support ePub4 or if new ones support ePub3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are confusing ePub2.0 vs ePub 3.0.  If I recall ePub 4 is for Google only.  If you are worried about older devices I would focus on validating your `.epub` file with a [2.0 validation tool](http://validator.idpf.org/).

To answer your question if its backwards, yes, **only if it validates across the board**:

**Example:**

```
<File>
    <Name>foo.epub</Name>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="230">
        <Version>3.0.0</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="177">
        <Version>1.2.0</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="149">
        <Version>1.1.0</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="156">
        <Version>1.0.5</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="201">
        <Version>1.0.4</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="182">
        <Version>1.0.3</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="193">
        <Version>1.0.2</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
    <ValidationReport elapsedTimeInMillis="208">
        <Version>1.0.1</Version>
        <Valid>yes</Valid>
        <Errors size="0"/>
        <Warnings size="0"/>
    </ValidationReport>
</File>
```

The reason is because an `.epub` file can be accepted by some as a 3.0 valid ePub **ONLY** and it could still fail the ePub 2.0 validation.